# Can I set up a serial terminal (RS-232) without a pty?

Tags: tty, socat, pty

I have two computers that both have a RS-232 port on `/dev/ttyS0` connect together with a null modem.

I am trying to understand bit by bit how an external terminal worked in the old days, and how that relates to how linux works today.

I have gotten it to work like this:

main computer:

```
$ sudo socat /dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0 exec:"/bin/bash -i",pty,stderr,setsid,sigint,sane
```

terminal:

```
picocom -b 9600 /dev/ttyS0
```

However, that has `pty` in it - which is why I get this on the terminal:

```
# tty
/dev/pts/11
```

and you shouldn't need a pseudo tty if you have an actual real life tty should you?  I mean they were connecting terminals in with wires before they had pseudo anything weren't they?

So I have been trying to mix and match socat options to make it with with no pty, but with no luck.  If I can anything appears in my terminal computer, there are no carriage returns or job control and `tty` says "not a tty".

I have to admit I don't understand the socat syntax (or terminal settings) - I was hoping to see the correct answer, and understand the syntax from there.

Could somebody either tell me how to make a remote terminal with no pty, or help me accept that it's not possible?

Comment: You fired your command under some Xterm didn't you ? Do you get means to access the system console and retry your experiments ?

Comment: you mean like - ctrl+alt+Fx?

Comment: You could start the tty with `getty`.  something like `getty -8 9600 ttyS0` should do.

Comment: @Alex028502 : Yes indeed ! And from there… can't you forget everything about ptys ?

Comment: @MC68020 yeah - I tried that - I actually tried it by swapping the computers, since the "terminal" is arch linux with no gui... and I got the same message - so I know it's not my computer

Comment: @stoney with getty, as soon as I open picocom on the terminal, getty exits with status 1

Comment: sorry the problem with this was that I left in `sane` when I took out `pty` - I am going to update the question

Comment: While I don't think this will answer the question about whether a pty is needed on a physical terminal, you may find this write-up interesting (as I did):  https://blog.nelhage.com/2009/12/a-brief-introduction-to-termios/

Answer (score 1):

If you start `getty` from the command line, you might need to run it as root and wrap it into a loop:

```
while true; do getty -8 9600 ttyS0; done
```

One invocation of `getty` gives you just one session, or a set of usually 3 login attempts, or until the serial port gets a hang-up signal. If `picocom` sends a hang-up initially to reset the serial line, it would cause the first `getty` to exit.

If a `getty` process is not terminated early by a serial port hang-up signal, then it will set up the TTY device, send the contents of `/etc/issue` to the terminal, and then present a login prompt. If a valid username is entered, `getty` will `exec()` (note: **without** `fork()`ing first) `/bin/login`, which will usually invoke the PAM libraries to handle the password prompt and the rest of the user session set-up. As part of that procedure, the identity of the process will be switched to the user that is logging in, and then the process that started as `getty` and then turned into `login` will again call `exec()` to become the user's shell. If that process dies **for any reason**, the user's session will end, and a new `getty` process will be started for a new login.

Running a `getty` manually in a loop might be a good way to "visualize" what needs to be happening, but it is not the proper way for long-term use.

All the `getty` processes are really intended to be started by `init` and restarted whenever the process that started its life as `getty` (and gets transformed into the user's shell on a successful login) dies... so on a modern Linux distribution that uses `systemd`, the command to make a `getty` run on a serial port connected to a terminal is usually:

```
systemctl start serial-getty@ttyS0.service
```

To make it persist over reboots, you'll also need a

```
systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
```

If you are using classic SysVinit instead, there should be commented-out example lines in `/etc/inittab` file: just uncomment the appropriate line, then run `telinit q` to make SysVinit re-read its configuration, and `init` should immediately start a `getty` process for the terminal and keep restarting it as necessary.